# Azure AKS Virtual Nodes not cleaning up succeeded Container Instances

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

I'm using AKS Virtual Nodes (backed by Azure Container Instances) to run one time jobs. Each triggered job will create a new Container Instance running that specific container.

Once the job is done, the Container Instance is put in the state "Succeeded". Later, a new job is started and a new Container Instance is created. And so on...

There is nothing cleaning up old succeeded Container Instances, so after a while new jobs will fail with the following error:

```
Warning  ProviderCreateFailed  27s   virtual-node-aci-linux/pod-controller  containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdateSender: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ContainerGroupQuotaReached" Message="Resource type 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups' container group quota 'ContainerGroups' exceeded in region 'northeurope'. Limit: '100', Usage: '100' Requested: '1'."
```

So my questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong? Should each new job run a container in an already existing Container Instance? I've found no configuration that suggests this however.
2. Can I enable something so that old succeeded (or failed) Container Instances are cleaned up so that I don't hit the quota?